# Is the function $f(x)=[a,x]$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Let $[a,b]$ a real closed intervel

Let $f(x)=[a,x]$ the function the $\forall x \in [a,b]$ associates the interval $[a,x]$

I would like to know that is the easiest topology so that f is continuous.

thanks

Comment: What is the topology on the range of $f$?

Comment: What are you regarding as the image space for $f$?  The collection of subsets of $[a,b]$?  Something else?

Comment: You need to specify your codomain is it $\mathcal{P}([a,b])$ is it some subset of that?

Comment: i haven't specified codomain because it could be simply all intervals $[a,x]$

Comment: i haven't specified a topology just to find one very simple

Comment: So you need to define a topology on $\{[a,c]|a\leq c\leq b\}$?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe yes...so that f is continuous

Comment: Well, if you declare the codomain, $X$, to be the set of intervals of the form $[a,x]$ for $x\in [a,b]$ then $X$ is naturally equivalent to $[a,b]$, under $f$ as it happens, so we can simply use the usual topology on $[a,b]$ in which case $f$ is clearly continuous (it is the identity map).

Comment: @lulu ok so i declare the codomain all interavals $[a,x]$ with $x \in [a,b]$ f will be continue?

Comment: Tautologically, yes.   I am defining the topology on the codomain to be the same as the topology on the domain (having identified the codomain and the domain via $f$).  Note:  this is all a bit circular...I'm not sure what content you hope to find in it.

Comment: The [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) may be of interest to you. It generates a rather nice topology on the set of closed subintervals and your function is continuous with respect to it.

Comment: ok  @lulu for now  it's sufficient, thanks so much

Comment: ok @mlk i have to prove that a function is continuous and i started for this little step. thanks for your hit

Comment: The easiest is by far the indiscrete topology.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli thanks i'll try

Comment: @lulu Declaring all $[a,c]$ as open: how would the union of some intervals of the type $[a,c+1/n]$ belong to that topology?

Comment: Alternatively, if you view your relation as a correspondence rather than a function there are two natural notions of continuity, upper- and lower- hemicontinuity, both of which are satisfied by your relation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemicontinuity

Comment: @MichaelHoppe  Not sure I follow.  I am not declaring $[a,x]$ to be open.  the OP has declared the codomain $X$ to be the set of intervals of the form $[a,x]$ for $x\in [a,c]$.  It is clear that $X$ is equivalent to the interval $[a,c]$ and I am using the natural topology on that interval.

Comment: @lulu Well, any union of open sets must be open, too.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe  I am still missing your point.  My argument is (or is intended to be) nearly tautological.  The Domain is the interval $I=[a,c]$, thus the set of real numbers $a≤x≤c$.  The Codomain, $X$, is nominally the collection of intervals $[a,x]$ with $x\in [a,c]$  and I am identifying $X$ with $I$ via $[a,x]\mapsto x$.  I am then saying that, under this identification, the topologies on $I,X$ are the same (this defines a topology on $X$).  Then the OP's map $f$ is simply the identity which, when viewed as a function from a topological space to itself, is always continuous.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe  If you permit my identification of $X$ with $I$ then you can't argue that I haven't defined a topology.  Presumably the OP intends the natural topology on $I$ (open sets are the intersection of open sets in $\mathbb R$ with $I$).  But whatever topology on $I$ the OP has in mind, I simply give $X$ the same one (under my identification).

Comment: @lulu If $T$ is a topological space

Comment: @MichaelHoppe  No idea what you have in mind.  If you think I have said something incorrect (always possible) please post what you consider a valid  solution to the problem below.  But in any case please stop writing cryptic comments to me.

Comment: @lulu If $T$ is a topological space, $M$ a set and $f\colon T\mapsto M$ a bijection, then $f$ induces a topology on $M$ such that $f$ is continuous: just let the open sets of $M$ be the images of the open sets in $T$ under $f$.  Now $f\colon [a,b]\mapsto \{[a,c]|a\leq c\leq b\}$, $f(x):=[a,x]$ is a bijection.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe  For the last time, I have no idea what point you are trying to make.  Please stop writing to me.